# Vue select value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some problems with vue select. I have one function that should return id as value and show text as option, but it's returning full object of selected value. For example:

I'm mapping selectable options from my backend that returns like:

```
    {
                "id": 179,
                "name": "Poland",
                "text": "Poland",
                "value": "Poland"
            },
            {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "Hungary",
                "text": "Hungary",
                "value": "Hungary"
            },
        {
            "value": "select_value"
        }
```

And my vue select looks like:

```
<v-select id="country" v-model="product_info.country" :options="activeCountries" :selectable="option => ! option.value.includes('select_value')" label="text" />
```

and Vue return a full object of selected value, for example

```
"country":{
            "id":100,
            "name":"Hungary",
            "text":"Hungary",
            "value":"Hungary"
         },
```

How do I specify in my select form to return only id for, for example:

```
"country":100
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong in v-select, but if you think that it's the problem somewhere else in the code, I will add more code from my app to resolve the problem.

Comment: Could you add that you are using Vuetify please, otherwise it can be seen as misleading

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to use the `item-value` prop like this:

```
<v-select item-value="id" id="country" v-model="product_info.country" :options="activeCountries" :selectable="option => ! option.value.includes('select_value')" label="text" />
```

you can see more on the vuetify documentation(https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props)